# Why doesn't my gdb debugger go step by step?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I have two versions of the same project written by others. In one project, if I set a break point at somewhere, it displays this first below. Then I can go through step by step for each lone, which is good.

```
  (gdb) break CTag::addInduce
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x4ee38c: file /data0/src/module/third/CTag.cpp, line 2474.
```

However, in another version of the project, the debugger doesn't go step by step as expected and the display info shorter when I set a break point as below:

```
(gdb) break CTag::addInduce
      Breakpoint 1 at 0x7e4476
```

Now if I do 'run', it seems it stops at the break point:

```
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function _ZN10CTag13addInduce,
which has no line number information.
```

Then do another 'n', it doesn't go to next line but exit from the function. What caused this? I want to be able to step through each line of the code.

Comment: Don't you wanna use "step" instead of "next"?

Comment: *"which has no line number information"* indicates that debug information is missing or incomplete. You should ensure that executable (and dlls) are build with proper debug information.

Comment: Is the other version built with optimizations?

Comment: How to check? @RetiredNinja

Comment: @user7860670 How to ensure they. are built with proper debug info?

Comment: You need to check that appropriate arguments are passed to compiled when building. Such as `-ggdb3` or `/DEBUG`. Limiting optimizations also helps to improve debugging experience.